# Cannot get out of the box Visual Studio 2015 sample to work in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I must be missing something. I did this

1. Download VS2015
2. Create new ASP.NET 5 preview site (With Azure and details).
3. Run locally and verify it works
4. Publish with all the default settings. Success!
5. Goto site. DOES NOT WORK. It only says.

This web app has been successfully created....

What is going on  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try refreshing your browser.  Often times if you visit the site before a deployment as well as after a deployment, the browser caches your site.  You can alternatively try "incognito mode" or "private browsing".

This should force a get on the site, which may be the particular issue you are running into.

Comment: I don't that is it. Can you deploy the ASP.NET 5 preview to a Azure site?

Comment: you are right.. I just came back and its working.. I thought I refreshed back when I first deployed it

Comment: Can you mark as official answer since this answered it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the app that you're publishing to Azure a .NET 4.6 app? 4.6 Framework isn't yet supported on the Azure platform - we're updating the platform to support the new framework over the next 1-2 months. Can you confirm the framework version of the app you're trying to deploy?

Comment: Well it is ASP.NET 5... yet the drop down when I make a web site says .NET 4.6... it is all pretty confusing..